# Azure API App Node.js deployment issues

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-api-apps

I'm testing Azure API App service with a Node.js (Express, Swaggerize, Sequelize and SQLlite). So far, everything is working in my development workstation, but I bumping into some issues when trying to deploy the app.

First, I created the API App "container" and I've connected my VSTS Git repo with the API container. Everything works well when pushing code to the repo (automatically the container gets all the changes in few seconds).

But... (question(s) following)

1. How can I resolve my Node dependencies? (so far, I've been invoking "npm install" manually through container console. I don't want to push my packages in the GIT repo
2. I cannot use SQLite dialect in sequelize because although the package seems to be inside of my app dependencies and in the node_modules directory, my apps still throws an exception

   ```
   Wed Mar 02 2016 16:57:16 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time): Unaught exception: Error: Please install sqlite3 package manually
   at new ConnectionManager (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\sqlite\connection-manager.js:24:11)
   at new SqliteDialect (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\sqlite\index.js:12:28)
   at new Sequelize (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:213:18)
   at Object.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\app\models\index.js:8:17)
   at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
   at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
   at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
   at Object.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\app\app.js:11:14)
   at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
   at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
   at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
   at Object.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\server.js:3:1)
   at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
   ```

Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: Do you use `npm install packagename --save` ?

Comment: Of course! I did that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the issue was caused by missing the npm package `sqlite3`. So you need to install the package manually, but the installation will be failed because the installation for package `sqlite3` need `gyp` compiler (according to the description of the package [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3)) that not support on Azure App Service.

You can refer to the section `Native Modules` of the doc [Using Node.js Modules with Azure applications](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/nodejs-use-node-modules-azure-apps/#nodejs-modules) to know the reason and how to work around.

Comment: I see what you mean. But, May I expect the same odd behavior if I switch my sequelize dialect to MySQL or any other? I mean, is there any Node.js DB module that is not native? Or maybe I should move the API DB to another PaaS service?

Comment: @javierglozano It depends on the node package like [`mysql`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql)  that is written in JavaScript, does not require compiling.

Comment: Thanks @Peter-Pan-msft but I wanted to try SQLite. Anyway, thanks for pointing me to that.

Comment: @javierglozano Do you mean this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite? It's wrapped `sqlite3`, so as the same as I said.